# Handling Laravel Links on Vue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

We are using Vue to `get` and `post` requests to Laravel API. I'm wondering if there is a way to get the URL using Laravel function or route name.

Using Laravel/Traditional way, we can do something on the form

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => [ 'FoosController@update',$foo->id ], 'method' => 'post', 'files'=>true]) !!}
    //FORM
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

or

```
route('foo.update');
```

Is there a way on `Vue` that we can do this? Just supply the function or route name?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look into this https://github.com/tighten/ziggy

Answer (score 0):

You can send it as a component property. like this:

```
<Component foo_route="{{route('foo.update')}}"></Component>
```

And after you can use it in your component like this:

```
this.foo_route
```

Comment: First part you need to add in .blade.php, and second part in .vue files